# Change size of a WatermarkText into a WatermarkTextBox with WinRT XAML Toolkit

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, font-size, watermark, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I use this lib : http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/
I want to specify the FontSize of the WatermarkText, how can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Watermark` property instead of the `WatermarkText` one to put anything you want as your watermark - e.g. a `TextBlock` with any properties you want. You can also use the `WatermarkTextStyle` property when using `WatermarkText` and specify the `Style` to use with the provided watermark `TextBlock` - something like:

```
<xc:WatermarkTextBox
    WatermarkText="Type something">
    <xc:WatermarkTextBox.WatermarkTextStyle>
        <Style
            TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter
                Property="FontSize"
                Value="18" />
            ...
```

You can check the sample to see some options [here](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c5#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/WatermarkTextBoxTestPage.xaml).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is a bit strange because when i use     <xc:WatermarkTextBox.WatermarkTextStyle>
I have this error : Error 8 the property attached to 'WatermarkTextStyle' can't be found on the type 'WatermarkTextBox'. In my xaml page because I already have a datacontext i put this at the top :     xmlns:ctl="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
    xmlns:Extensions="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions" maybe because of that it doesn't work ? (of course I modify the xc by ctl)

Comment: Does the project build though? The designer/xaml editor often reports false errors.

Comment: No, can't compile. 3 errors : the member "WatermarkTextStyle" is unreconized or not accessible. and two linked to this error

Comment: Maybe you are using an older version of the toolkit. If you look at the sample it does exactly that

Comment: Download latest source. It might be more up to date.